# Unsatisfied dependencies for type with qualifiers @default at injection point

Tags: java, maven, dependency-injection, java-ee-7

I'm working on a project with javaee-7. I have developed a new functionality in an external library and now I want to use the logic developed in the library in a micro-service.

Code from library

```
public class Address {
    public void addFormattedAddress(String country) {
        if (country.equals("BR")) {
                object.setFormattedAddress(new AddressFormatterForBR().createAddress(country));
            } else if (country.equals("CN")) {
                object.setFormattedAddress(new AddressFormatterForCN().createAddress(country));
            }
        }
    }
```

Code from micro-service

```
@Inject
private Address address;
.....
listOfObjects.forEach(object -> responseAddressFormatter.addFormattedAddress(country));
```

When I want to start the microservice I did the following steps:

```
 1. mvn clean install --> here I received BUILD SUCCESS
 2. docker-compose build --> everything looks fine
 3. docker-compose up ---> here I received this error:
```

**Exception while loading the app : CDI deployment failure:WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type Address with qualifiers @Default
    webapp_1            |   at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject private**

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your Address bean is not getting scanned. Are you sure you don't want to put any annotation on you Address class?